# 3 divs as background

Tags: css, image, html, background-image, repeat

I've been working on this for a couple of hours and can't seem to wrap my head around it.
I have three images, below, and I would like the text content to sit on top of these, but how do I do it?
The middle image is the image that would need to repeat as the container div expands.

Okay, I do apologise for my lack of information, it's a little late and I'm not exactly thinking straight. I would like to comprise a container with all three images. The minimum height of this container would be the top and bottom image. As contents starts to overflow this minimum height, the middle image would start to repeat to accommodate for more height.

Top:
[alt text http://files.droplr.com/files/45544730/INDf3.Page.png](http://files.droplr.com/files/45544730/INDf3.Page.png)

Middle repeating:
[alt text http://files.droplr.com/files/45544730/INE5i.Page-Tile.png](http://files.droplr.com/files/45544730/INE5i.Page-Tile.png)

Bottom:
[alt text http://files.droplr.com/files/45544730/INFbt.Page-Bottom.png](http://files.droplr.com/files/45544730/INFbt.Page-Bottom.png)

Comment: What about showing the code that you wrote so far?

Comment: If you want to make the text go on top of the middle one, it's trivial.
If not, you're in for position juggling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### my solution:

I usually do it like this:

```
<div class="box">
  <span class="header"></span>
  content
  <span class="bottom"></span>
</div>
```

css:

```
.box { background: url(middle.png) repeat-y left top; }
  .box .header { background: url(top.png) no-repeat; display: block; margin-bottom: -480px; /* +set height and width */}
  .box .bottom { background: url(bottom.png) no-repeat; display: block; /*+ height and width*/}
```

usually, bottom of div is so small it's ok to leave it blank (to add spacing to whole design). Also, negative margin-bottom size should be : -(`height` - `what_you_want_to_remain_empty`) - i.e. if your `.box .header` image has `540px` and you want to leave top `50px` empty, you'll set `-490px` as I had.

Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

```
TRY FOLLOWING

<div style="background:url(../top.png) no-repeat;">
  Top
</div>

<div style="background:url(../middle.png)">
  Middle:
</div>

<div style="background:url(../bottom.png) no-repeat;">
  Bottom
</div>
```

Give class instead and handle it in your stylesheets

Comment: This works, but I would add specific height specs to the CSS on the top and bottom elements.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class='top'>
</div>
<div class='middle'>
</div>
<div class='bottom'>
</div>
```

Give each `div` seperate `background` CSS styling.

---

*But I would suggest,*
Give `background` styling to the text `div`, along with `box-shadow` and `border`.
In this case, you will need only the *middle* image.

Comment: -1. I think he wants the content to be in one div that spans the whole background, without having to separate content into the different div's

Comment: @David: the first method is a little hackish (top and bottom would be mostly static and the text would always go to the middle div.)

Comment: @David I think the 3 div solution is the easiest to implement and will provide the functionality the OP is looking for.

Comment: funny how the answer with highest votes is same as mine, but i get the -1 votes :D. oh! i know why, i didn't spoon feed.

Comment: @Seth M: Removed my -1 (what's the point, all the other ones come with the same hackish suggestion). Were CSS3 an option, I would definitely go for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Having the code so far would be helpful, but I will give it a whirl.

You are going to need a container for each image.

```
<div class="head"></div>
<div class="text">TEXT HERE</div>
<div class="foot"></div>
```

--css--

```
div.head { 
  background-image:url('top.png');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
div.text {
  background-image:url('middle.png');
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
div.foot {
  background-image:url('bottom.png');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

I would probably want to make the first image about the same size as the last image and let the 2nd image fill in as needed.

Answer (score 0):

i think in Seth M's answer, you need to provide height for top(head) & bottom(foot) div.

then it will work properly.

Comment: I was assuming the OP could figure out the heights.

Answer (score 0):

```
div.box:before {content:url(top.png);}
div.box {
  background-image:url(middle.png) repeat-y;
  width:?;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
div.box:after {content:url(bottom.png);}
```

It's a neat thing, which puts the top and bottom pics as images inside the box, but always first and last. Of course it doesn't work if you have margins or paddings, but try doing this too:

```
div.box > div {padding:10px;}

<div class="box"><div>
  Content goes here
</div></div>
```

That should give you exactly what you want, in a sort of weird way. Beware that older browsers won't support these CSS rules.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a ful code with HTML/CSS using the images you posted. The header portion is rather 'tall'. I assume it's part of your design.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div.top, div.body, div.footer {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 844px;
color: #ffffff;
background-color: #666666;
padding-left: 10px; /* edit accordingly */
}

div.top {
background: url(http://files.droplr.com/files/45544730/INDf3.Page.png) no-repeat;
height: 426px;
}
div.body {
background: url(http://files.droplr.com/files/45544730/INE5i.Page-Tile.png) repeat-y;
height: 200px;
}
div.footer {
background: url(http://files.droplr.com/files/45544730/INFbt.Page-Bottom.png) no-repeat left bottom;
height: 100px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="top">top
</div>
<div class="body">body
</div>
<div class="footer">footer
</div>
</body>
</html>
```